# get date order by day and month in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am storing the date as "14-02-2013" in date column of my table. Now when I get the date using "ORDER BY" then it should display the output as

```
14-02-2013
15-03-2013
24-05-2013
```

How to write the query for this. i.e getting order by day and month.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SQLITE Manager.

Comment: order by date_column_name

Comment: I executed the query as "Select name,date from HolidayList order by date". But it is sorting only the day but the month is not coming by order.

Comment: What is your data type for that column - is it an actual temporal type (date/time/timestamp), or are you storing it as a formatted string (which, especially in that format, is usually a bad idea)?  How should a date of `14-02-2012` be sorted?  How about `14-01-2013` and `14-03-2013`?

Comment: I am storing the date with datatype as strin

Comment: Why don't you use one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime)?

Answer (score 0):

Use DATE (or DATETIME) type in your column. Otherwise you will have to perform operations on string representation of date, which is not cool and will cost some extra time to perform

Answer (score 0):

Try one of following:

```
Select *  from Table1 order by date(dtcolumn) Asc
Select * from Table1 order by strftime('%d-%m-%Y', dtcolumn)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this query

```
Select * from Table1 Order By mydatecol Asc
```

Answer (score -1):

Given you store your date as a temporal data type you can use

```
select * from your_date_table order by date(your_date_column) ASC
```

If you store it as a string(which you should not do), you can try

```
select * from your_date_table order by your_date_column ASC
```

Here is the doc for the [sqlite date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)